# Creating an extended partition

Tags: linux, partitioning, hard-drive

I'm trying to create an extended partition. In GParted, I shrunk the size of the existing partition and now want to create a new EXTENDED partition in the free, unallocated space. GParted only lets me create a PRIMARY partition. What am I doing wrong here?

Here's what I've got right now:

[image]

You can actually ignore the flag for the swap as "boot." That was me just messing around trying to get it to work. I've removed that flag. Not sure how the question of boot affects all of this...maybe it factors in somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have an extended partition; adding a second can lead to undefined behavior on some operating systems. Resize the existing extended partition instead.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your existing extended partition is a fixed size and there is no more room in it to add new "sub-partitions".  The only free space is in front of the extended portion.

To fix this you'll need to:

1) move the extended partition to the beginning of the free space (which will then move the free space so it's after the extended partition).

2) extend the size of the main extended partition to fill the remaining space.

3) add a new partition after the swap partition (assuming you want to keep it) that is within the extended partition.

PS: backup anything important first!

Comment: I think you should also mention, that one extended partition can hold several logical partitions. So there is no need to have more than one extended one.